# How to bring BASH back to its default settings

Tags: bash, default

Made some interface changes to BASH that I want to undo and change BASH back to its default setting.

```
In the ~/.bash_profile file
PROMPT_COLOR='\e[00m\e[38;05;166m'
export PS1='\['$PROMPT_COLOR'\][\h]: \w\$\[\e[0m\] '
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

the above is the code I entered

thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the lines in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Do you want to use the variables from your `.bash_profile` file, or the global settings? (i.e. the default from e.g. `/etc/skel/.bash_profile`)?

Comment: Delete the file. Log out.  Log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the  new lines with `#`. Save the file. Type `exit` to exit the shell. Log in / open a new shell.

Comment: Instead of exiting and new login you can just do `source ~/.bashrc`